# Repeated points in polygon when using svg.draw.js

Tags: javascript, polygon, svg.js

When I create a polygon using `draw()` it inserts some points 2 times. Eg When I create a polygon with 4 points

```
<polygon id="SvgjsPolygon1063" points="179,177 179,177 397,147 323,381 323,381 88,350 88,350" class="labelbox shape"></polygon>
```

If I delete repeated points manually from the element I see there is no difference in the shape. But if I move or reshape the polygon it again inserts 7 points.

- In case of 3 points (triangle) polygon, total points are 5.
- In case of 4 points polygon, total points are 7.
- In case of 5 points polygon, total points are 8.

It'll be helpful if you can explain the logic so I can persist unique points and restore them properly.

Simplified Code from [main application](https://naturalintelligence.github.io/imglab/v2.html);

```
var createPolygon = function(){//TODO: bug: creating duplicate points
    var poly =  myCanvas.nested().polygon().addClass('labelpolygon shape').draw();
    poly.resize();
    poly.parent().draggable();

    poly.on('drawstart', function(e){
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                poly.draw('done');
                poly.off('drawstart');
            }
        });
    });

    return poly;
}
myCanvas.on('mousedown', function(event){

    if(!alreadyDrawing){
        var currentTool = createPolygon(event,myCanvas);

        currentTool.on('drawstart', function(){
            alreadyDrawing = true;
        });
        currentTool.on('resizedone', function(){
            //update data
        });
        currentTool.draw(event);
        selectedElement = currentTool;
    }
});

myCanvas.on('mouseup', function(event){
    selectedElement.draw(event);
});

function attachEvents(currentTool){
    currentTool.parent().on('click',function(e) {
        currentTool.selectize({ rotationPoint: false});
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show your code!

Comment: @Fuzzyma https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/imglab/issues/32

Comment: Create a [minimal verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/) and post relevant code parts in the question. Links to somewhere else outdate fast and this question becomes uncomplete

Comment: I've added the code from main application to this question. I believe there is some issue with event handling

Comment: You call draw and then you call it again with an event. Decide for one

Comment: After your hint, I tested the code and found that if I comment `mouseup` event, and `draw()` in createPolygon() then it works as expected. But as I wanted to have a common code for event handling for rect, circle, polygon etc. it gives issue. However since your suggestion solve at least this problem, please post as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`draw` has a standard behavior when you call it without an event. It automatically binds to the `click` event in that case. When you then start to call `draw` with an event, too. It will mess up the logic and produces the result you are getting.

To solve this issue, decide for one option.
If you want more control, pass the event. If you are fine with the click behavior, just call `draw` without any parameters

Comment: Yes I had put a condition in mousedown event.